# Drillthrough disabled after adding CUBESET function

Tags: excel, excel-2010, mdx, cube, drillthrough

Originally, I have using CUBEVALUE function in Excel 2010 and it is working fine with the drillthrough function. The cubevalue function looks like this:

```
=CUBEVALUE(connection, member_expression1, member_expression2, member_expression3)
```

When I try to add CUBESET function inside the CUBEVALUE function, it can retrieve correct values but the drillthrough function does not work (Right click on the data cell -> Additional Actions -> Nothing shown). The CUBESET function looks like this:

```
CUBESET(connection, "EXCEPT(Set_expression1, Set_expression2)")
```

Is there any workaround to this issue?

Comment: I've used the `CUBEVALUE` and `CUBESET` functions quite a bit - please can you clarify what you mean by "drillthrough function"? Also can you please add the nested function you are using in your post?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. For drillthrough function, you may refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166579(v=sql.100).aspx) and [Example](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3168/excel-actions-and-drill-down-for-sql-server-analysis-services/).

Comment: great references KingKong .... I didn't realise these capabilities existed!

Comment: I'm guessing that drillthrough will only function against a specific value - if you have a set then it does not know which value to drillthrough against? So maybe just a limitation of the functionality.